# Using Jquery to append form field's value to form action?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a simple form with a few textboxes on it. I would like to capture the input of the textboxes, modify it slightly and then append it to the form action URL.

```
  $('.myBox').on('change', function (event) {
        var myVal = $(this).val();
        $('form').attr('action').appendTo("&MyVal="+myVal);
    });
```

The above code doesn't work because there is no appendTo to the attr value. Is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: Why do you want/need to do this? What's the actual goal?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your syntax isn't quite right as you want to update the value of the `action` attribute, not `append` an element. Try this:

```
$('.myBox').on('change', function (event) {
    var myVal = $(this).val();
    $('form').attr('action', function(i, value) {
        return value + "&MyVal=" + myVal;
    });
});
```

Comment: Wont the get parameter be added each time the select box has changed, making redundancy in the action url ? (well latest param should override the first ones)

Comment: @f00bar it will indeed. I'll leave it to OP to fix if that's unintended behaviour.

Comment: And actually for whatever reason the example is not "updating" the form action. Is your example suppose to?

Comment: @JohnS what was the typo?

Comment: The ")" after the return value

Comment: @JohnS ah! Thanks. Completely missed it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this one:

```
$("form").attr('action',$("form").attr('action')+ "&MyVal=test");
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually came up with something similar.

```
            $('.Mybox').on('change', function (event) {
            var action = $('form').attr('action');
            $('form').attr('action',action+"&test");
        });
```

But I think I like yours better.  Thanks